# Hiding Worksheet while copying and pasting

Tags: vba, excel

I am developing some Excel VBA routines that take data from one sheet, generate other workbooks, then copy various sheets and data between them.

I am doing a lot of switching between workbooks/sheets back and forth.

is there a simple way to hide everyting until the end and show some sort of progress bar?

I somply don't want to hide/show things when I need to copy/paste them...I would like excel to do everything silently in background.

Any way to do this??

Comment: Please investigate `Application.ScreenUpdating`. It's not exactly what you're asking for, but you should be aware of it. It will speed up your code too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can temporarily disable **ScreenUpdating**

```
Sub SilentRunning()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '
    '   do your thing
    '
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about it. This seems to be the right one I was looking for. Neater and faster as @Doug Glancy pointed out

Answer (score 4):

@garys-student nailed it on disabling screen updating -- if you want to update a progress bar for particularly antsy users, you can use this:

[image]

```
Application.StatusBar = "Processing row " & Idx & " of " & _
    LastRow & "... " & Format(Idx / LastRow, "0%") & " complete"
'
' do other stuff
'
Application.StatusBar = False 'reset the status bar
```

Comment: Hi Dan: ....................will the status bar update if screen updating is disabled??

Comment: Fortunately it does. The screenshot I pulled is from a bit of code that disables screen updating but keeps the status bar rolling. Interesting stuff!

Comment: Interesting. I would like to show a UserForm with a ProgressBar, but this aproach is nice indeed!!!

Comment: DoEvents causes a form to update itself (ProgressBar width and % completion) even if Application.ScreenUpdating = False